# Python script file containing parameters fails to execute in batch file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a simple Windows batch file containing just one line:

```
python c:\temp\script.py
```

The input file to be executed by python, script.py, contains these lines:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os
os.chdir("C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/apps/Python27/Scripts")
code = "python –m pip install –U pip setuptools"
os.system(code)
```

Script.py of course executes fine on its own, but when run from within the setup.bat file, the following error results:

```
python: can't open file 'ΓÇôm': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It is stumbling on the "-m" option in the script.py command line, because if a command without signed options is passed in the script.py file (i.e., "code=pip install setuptools"), it works just fine. Any substring with a "-" character messes the batch file execution up.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Unless you have a file named `ΓÇôm`, it appears you have an encoding issue.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Yes, I agree it's encoding-- that's why I thought the first line specifying the utf-8 encoding would help. Haven't ever had a file named "ΓÇôm" but I'll keep this in mind for that occasion :-).

Answer (score 0):

You need pip to be installed prior to executing the command.  Something like this should work.

```
import pip

# to install requirements
pip.main(['install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'])

# to install one package
pip.main(['install', 'package_name'])
```

Comment: Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: No, pip is installed (that's why code = "pip install setuptools" works OK. Thanks for responding though.